# Override to_xml for all objects in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml-serialization

Looking to override to_xml method for everything in my app and having a tough time.

The reason is pretty trivial, I need to get rid of the :indent formatting it does by default.  I've heard the arguments that "this is a view" problem, and that I should just override to_xml in my models where I need this.

The problem is that I return this stuff programmatically and having :skip_types set makes my responses incorrect.  They're incorrect when you have an empty array, and you end up with:
\n   
Suddenly it's a string value read by the client cotaining \n  (<< there's a bunch of whitespace there, too, but stack overflow doesn't seem to like it).  I also don't like the idea of having to override the same thing in 30 places.

That said, the fix is really easy, I just can't seem to put it in the right place.  Just looking for help on where to put this.  And a second set of eyes on my fix would be appreciated, too.

My fix is

```
alias __old_to_xml to_xml
def to_xml(options = {})
  options.merge!(:indent => 0)
  __old_to_xml(options) 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I generally agree with the apprehension others have about the approach, but I think you could monkey patch it by adding a file to config/initializers with the following:

```
module ActiveRecord::Serialization
  alias __old_to_xml to_xml
  def to_xml(opts={})
    __old_to_xml opts.merge(:indent => 0)
  end
end
```

If you're on Rails 3, I believe you'll want ActiveModel::Serializers::Xml instead of ActiveRecord::Serialization, but no guarantees.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I'll give it a try in a few minutes here.
So, tangent, but I don't get the apprehension with the approach other than I'm setting up for a bad rails upgrade at some point.  There's a display decision being made in the class -- they've decided that the default display is :indent = 2.  Is the consensus really that I should either have :indent => 0 (or some other display logic) either in 40 odd return controllers or 15 odd models' to_xml methods.  Is there another approach I'm missing to prevent the to_xml methods from including '\n' characters that's better?